# Init order within a package

Tags: go

I have files:

```
main/
    a.go
    b.go
    c.go
```

a.go:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func init(){
    fmt.Println("a")
}

func main(){}
```

b.go:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func init(){
    fmt.Println("b")
}
```

c.go:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func init(){
    fmt.Println("c")
}
```

In what order will the strings be outputted?

Comment: Related: [What does lexical file name order mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650965/what-does-lexical-file-name-order-mean)

Comment: Though the spec says the build system is "encouraged" to provide filenames in lexical order, it's not mandatory. If your files are in a single package, it seems fairly easy to enforce an absolute order to ensure consistent behavior.

Answer (score 13):

The order that the respective filenames were passed to the Go compiler.

The [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) says "build systems are encouraged to present multiple files belonging to the same package in lexical file name order to a compiler" so it's a safe bet that `go build` does exactly that, and the inits will run in A-B-C order.

Comment: I'd say for that safe bet to be really safe, each file should provide a function named like `initA()`, `initB()` etc and one of those files should call them all in a well-defined sequence in its `init()`.  As an added bonus, and an important one, that would provide a clear hint to the reader.

Comment: Or better, if you have initialization that is order dependant, make those dependencies explicit. E.g. if you have `var a = fn()` in one file and `var fn = func() int { return 42 }` in another then the `fn` will always be initialized first; https://play.golang.org/p/W6UdA_6gSa (in other words it may make sense to rename one of the `init` functions and call it from another where needed).

Comment: It might be worth saying that the order of the `var` lines in https://play.golang.org/p/W6UdA_6gSa does matter if they were located within the `function main()` block