# What's the purpose of golang allowing multiple init in one package?

Tags: go, init

I know that golang allows multiple init in one package and even in one file.
I am wondering why? 
For example, if a pkg has many files, we could write multiple init then we could get lost in where to we should put init, and we could be also confused about the init order if we have multiple init in one pkg. (I mean is this better? we can only have 1 init, then we can have some initXXX, then put them into init, it seems quite clean.)
What's the advantage of doing this in code struct view?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This question may be somewhat opinion based, but using multiple package `init()` functions can make your code easier to read and maintain.

If your source files are large, usually you arrange their content (e.g. types, variable declarations, methods etc.) in some logical order. Allowance of multiple `init()` functions gives you the possibility to put initialization code near to the parts they ought to initialize. If this would not be allowed, you would be forced to use a single `init()` function per package, and put everything in it, far from the variables they need to initialize.

Yes, having multiple `init()` functions may require some care regarding the execution order, but know that using multiple `init()` functions is not a requirement, it's just a possibility. And you can write `init()` functions to not have "side" effects, to not rely on the completion of other `init()` functions.

If that is unavoidable, you can create one "master" `init()` which explicitly controls the order of other, "child" `init()` functions.

An example of a "master" `init()` controlling other initialization functions:

```
func init() {
    initA()
    initB()
}

func initA() {}
func initB() {}
```

In the above example, `initA()` will always run before `initB()`.

Relevant section from spec: [Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution).

Also see related question: [What does lexical file name order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650965/what-does-lexical-file-name-order-mean/31651094#31651094)

Answer (score 10):

Another use case for multiple `init()` functions is adding functionality based on build tags. The `init()` function can be used to add hooks into the existing package and extend its functionality.

The following is a condensed example demonstrating the addition of more commands to a CLI utility based on build tags.

```
package main

import "github.com/spf13/cobra"

var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{Use: "foo", Short: "foo"}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(
        &cobra.Command{Use: "CMD1", Short: "Command1"},
        &cobra.Command{Use: "CMD2", Short: "Command2"},
    )
}

func main() {
    rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

The above is the "vanilla" version of the utility.

```
// +build debugcommands

package main

import "github.com/spf13/cobra"

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(&cobra.Command{Use: "DEBUG-CMD1", Short: "Debug command1"})
}
```

The contents of the second file extends the standard command with additional commands that are mostly relevant during development.

Compiling using `go build -tags debugcommands` will produce a binary with the added commands, while omitting the `-tags` flag will produce a standard version.

Comment: You should probably have the `AddCommand` call in the first file also in a `init` function to showcase multiple inits, which is what this question is about. And also, deduplicating the commands you add there (either by removing the second or changing 1 to 2) would also be nice. I liked your usecase though.

Comment: @Adirio : Nice suggestion, that would provide a bit more symmetry. Don't have an IDE handy to check the change, though, so it'll have to wait a bit. :)

Comment: Is there any order in which these init commands are executed ?

Comment: @SumitMurari: Seems like it's most likely lexical order of the file names : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32829593/13075