# How do I split a package into multiple files when there are dependencies between their init() functions?

Tags: go, package

I have a go file for a package that is becoming unwieldy, so I want to split it into multiple logical files.

I have the files currently split (and abridged) like so:

```
// node.go
package schema

import (
    "github.com/graphql-go/graphql"
    "github.com/graphql-go/relay"
)

var nodeDefinitions *relay.NodeDefinitions

func init() {
    nodeDefinitions = relay.NewNodeDefinitions(relay.NodeDefinitionsConfig{
        IDFetcher: func(id string, info graphql.ResolveInfo) interface{} {
            ...
        },
        TypeResolve: func(value interface{}, info graphql.ResolveInfo) *graphql.Object {
            // based on the type of the value, return GraphQLObjectType
            switch value.(type) {
            default:
                return testType //Depends on the test.go
            }
        },
    })
}


//root.go
package schema

import (
    "github.com/graphql-go/graphql"
)

var Schema graphql.Schema

func init() {
    queryType := graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
        Name: "Query",
        Fields: graphql.Fields{
            "version": &graphql.Field{
                 Type: versionType, //Depends on testtype.go
                 ...
            },
            "node": nodeDefinitions.NodeField, //Depends on node.go
        },
    })

    Schema, _ = graphql.NewSchema(graphql.SchemaConfig{
        Query: queryType,
    })
}

//testtype.go
package schema

import (
    "github.com/graphql-go/graphql"
    "github.com/graphql-go/relay"
)

var testType *graphql.Object

func init() {
    testType = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
        ...
        Interfaces: []*graphql.Interface{
            nodeDefinitions.NodeInterface, //Depends on node.go
        },
    })
}
```

I then use the package in `main.go`:

```
result := graphql.Do(graphql.Params{
        Schema:        schema.Schema,
        RequestString: r.URL.Query()["query"][0],
    })
```

While the package builds correctly, it complains with an error when I run it:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x48e4b6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql.(*Object).Error(0x0, 0xc082003380, 0x3c)
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/definition.go:440 +0x26
test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql.defineFieldMap(0xda48b0, 0xc08206c780, 0xc0820550e0, 0xda
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/definition.go:498 +0x532
test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql.(*Object).Fields(0xc08206c780, 0xc08206c780)
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/definition.go:416 +0x106
test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql.typeMapReducer(0xc082055110, 0xda4560, 0xc08206c780, 0x0,
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/schema.go:208 +0x79a
test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql.NewSchema(0xc08206c780, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/schema.go:67 +0x809
test/testproject/schema.init.2()
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/schema/root.go:37 +0x244
test/testproject/schema.init()
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/schema/version.go:37 +0x5b
main.init()
        C:/go/src/test/testproject/main.go:37 +0x42
```

This is because:

```
node.go depends on testtype.go
testtype.go depends on node.go
root.go depends on node.go and testtype.go
```

`go build` builds the files in the page by sorting the filenames alphabetically: `node.go` then `root.go` then `testtype.go`.

If I rename `root.go` to `z.go`, it builds and runs correctly. Besides renaming `root.go` to `z.go` which is less than ideal, is there any other way I can get this working in a scalable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just one `init()` function and put everything in that.

Or if you want to stick with multiple `init()` functions in multiple `.go` files, then create one "master" init function that will be called `init()`, and rename other init functions, e.g. `initA()`, `initB()`, and call these from the master init in proper order:

```
func init() {
    initA()
    initB()
}
```

See related question+answer: [What does lexical file name order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650965/what-does-lexical-file-name-order-mean)

Comment: Is using a master `init()` to call `initA()`, `initB()` etc considered idiomatic go?

Comment: If you have dependencies between your init functions, yes, this is a good way which also documents the dependency, and makes sure your build will not depend on how the build system lists/proceeds with different files of a package.